# VLA warning for exactly matching prototype

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Gcc 11 added -Wvla-parameters to -Wall apparently, now, since I use -Werror always, I get an error like the following:

```
libtool: compile:  mpicc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../src/yaxt/src -I../include -I../include -I../../../src/yaxt/src/../include -DgFortran -pthread -g -pipe -O3 -march=native -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wstrict-overflow -Wno-error=unused-function -Wno-error=type-limits -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Werror -Wstrict-aliasing -fsanitize=undefined -MT xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.Tpo -c ../../../src/yaxt/src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.o
../../../src/yaxt/src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.c:239:9: error: mismatch in bound 1 of argument 7 declared as 'int (*)[(long int)(send_size_asize) - 1]' [https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wvla-parameter-Werror=vla-parameter]
  239 |   int (*send_size)[send_size_asize],
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../../../src/yaxt/src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.c:62:
../../../src/yaxt/src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.h:142:9: note: previously declared as 'int (*)[(long int)(send_size_asize) - 1]'
  142 |   int (*send_size)[send_size_asize],
      |   ~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:836: recipe for target 'xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.lo' failed
```

But the declaration at `src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.h:142`

```
PPM_DSO_INTERNAL size_t
xt_xmap_dist_dir_pack_intersections(
  enum xt_xmdd_direction target,
  size_t num_intersections,
  const struct isect *restrict src_dst_intersections,
  bool isect_idxlist_delete,
  size_t send_size_asize, size_t send_size_idx,
  int (*send_size)[send_size_asize],
  unsigned char *buffer, size_t buf_size, size_t *ofs, MPI_Comm comm);
```

matches the definition exactly:

```
size_t
xt_xmap_dist_dir_pack_intersections(
  enum xt_xmdd_direction target,
  size_t num_intersections,
  const struct isect *restrict src_dst_intersections,
  bool isect_idxlist_delete,
  size_t send_size_asize, size_t send_size_idx,
  int (*send_size)[send_size_asize],
  unsigned char *buffer, size_t buf_size, size_t *ofs, MPI_Comm comm)
{
  int prev_send_rank = -1;
  size_t num_send_indices_requests = 0;
  size_t origin = 1 ^ target, ofs_ = *ofs;
  int position = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_intersections; ++i)
  {
    /* see if this generates a new request? */
    int send_rank = src_dst_intersections[i].rank[target];
    num_send_indices_requests += send_rank != prev_send_rank;

    // pack rank
    XT_MPI_SEND_BUF_CONST int *prank
      = CAST_MPI_SEND_BUF(src_dst_intersections[i].rank + origin);
    if (send_rank != prev_send_rank && prev_send_rank != -1) {
      send_size[prev_send_rank][send_size_idx] = position;
      ofs_ += (size_t)position;
      position = 0;
    }
    prev_send_rank = send_rank;
    xt_mpi_call(MPI_Pack(prank, 1, MPI_INT, buffer+ofs_, (int)(buf_size-ofs_),
                         &position, comm), comm);
    // pack intersection
    xt_idxlist_pack(src_dst_intersections[i].idxlist, buffer+ofs_,
                    (int)(buf_size-ofs_), &position, comm);

    if (isect_idxlist_delete)
      xt_idxlist_delete(src_dst_intersections[i].idxlist);
  }
  if (prev_send_rank != -1)
    send_size[prev_send_rank][send_size_idx] = position;

  *ofs = ofs_ + (size_t)position;
  return num_send_indices_requests;
}
```

If anyone has any suggestion how to get rid of the warning (and allow users to stick to -Wall with gcc 11.1 subsequently), that would be highly appreciated.

I'm aware I can do something along the lines of

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wvla-parameter"
```

but that seems like the wrong approach.

creduce was less painful to get running than I expected.
This seems to be a bad interaction of sanitizer and VLA:
Minimal source to reproduce:

```
void a(long send_size_asize, int (*)[send_size_asize]);
void a(long send_size_asize, int (*)[send_size_asize]) {}
```

Command line to check:

```
gcc-11.1 -c -Wall -Werror -fsanitize=undefined mini.c
```

Sorry for forgetting to mention -fsanitize, I routinely have that on now, this is the first time it's given me trouble.

Submitted as [#10158](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101585) to gcc bugzilla.

Comment: Are you sure the compiler is complaining about the function definition and not somewhere that calls the function?  You've not provided us with an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  That makes it hard for us to determine what's going on.  Please work on producing an MCVE.

Comment: Is `send_size_asize` defined as a macro somewhere? Something converted that to `(long int)(send_size_asize) - 1`.

Comment: My [trivial attempts](https://godbolt.org/z/f98rx4Yfz) at reproducing the error were unsuccessful. What should we do to get the same error? Clone [master branch](https://gitlab.dkrz.de/dkrz-sw/yaxt/-/blob/master/src/xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.c#L239) and then....? Would you be able to create _the smallest possible_ reproducible source code with all the steps needed to build to reproduce the error? If you remove the function body, and all other functions, and all other source files, does it still reproduce the problem? Remove stuff until you find the exact source of the problem.

Comment: Since this is not the only change for GCC 11, I'm kind of in a tight position: I first need to get the source to build successfully with GCC 11 _and_ all other setups we currently support before pushing to the repo. I realize that having a minimal reproducer is desirable but also a non-trivial amount of work. I'll try to get there, but will first go with the pragma solution perhaps and report back when I got c-reduce to work out the details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Barmar, `send_size_asize` is not defined as a macro and can only be found in the two places shown in the above excerpt.

Comment: `(long int)(send_size_asize) - 1` must be coming from somewhere. Search for that throughout the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I can exclude the caller possibility: all callers are in other source files and not visible to the compiler when compiling the file in question.

Comment: OK — have you looked at the preprocessor output (`gcc -E xt_xmap_dist_dir_common.c` or thereabouts)?  You'll need the other preprocessor related command line options too.  Have you used `gcc -H` to see exactly which header files are included?